# Calling angular 2 element properties dynamically in html

Tags: html, angular

I have these 2 objects in my component:

- claim: Claim
- displayableColumns: ColumnSettings[];

**displayableColumns** contains the actual columns I want to display on the HTML page.

claim.component.html:

```
<div *ngFor="let column for displayableColumns">
    <div class="formGroup">
        <label>{{ column.ColumnName }}</label>
        <input type="text" value="{{ claim.[column.ColumnName] }}" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Obviously that **{{ claim.[column.ColumnName] }}** syntax doesn't exist.

Is there a way to call an element's property using a string?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what your data exactly looks like, however, what you want is actually possible (if I understand you correctly). There is a small issue in your code, the syntax is

```
 {{ claim[column.ColumnName] }}
```

So remove the additional . (dot) after claim.

Comment: I had written that to aid my explanation of what I needed, never thought it was actually valid syntax, it did need a slight fix like you mentioned though, thank you! Angular 2 is dope

Answer (score 0):

The value between the brackets can be any expression. Therefore, if the property name is stored in a variable, you have to use bracket notation like below

```
<div *ngFor="let column for displayableColumns">
    <div class="formGroup">
        <label>{{ column.ColumnName }}</label>
        <input type="text" value="{{ claim[column.ColumnName] }}" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Where column.ColumnName has to be one of your claims property.

Comment: Didn't I say that?